# Barra de progresso para slide jcarousel

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
// Carousel
$(function(){
  $(".peq-carousel").jCarouselLite({
    bntNext: '.next',
    bntPrev: '.prev',
    visible: 7,
    auto: 3000,
    speed: 800,
    vertical: true
  });
});

// Barra Progresso
function startbar(){
  var barr = document.getElementById('timeBar');
  var maxx = barr.max;
  var vall = barr.value;

  if ( vall < maxx ){
    barr.value++;
    setTimeout("startbar()", 7);
  }

  if ( vall >= maxx ){
    barr.value=0;
    startbar();
  }
}
```

A função que mostrei a cima, funciona muito bem o slide carousel.
Assim como a função da barra de progresso.
Mas como faço minha função de barra de progresso clicar no objeto "bntNext: '.next'"
Toda vez que ela zera..????
Onde nos comandos da barra de progresso, devo colocar um código, ou alguma variável...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você deseja disparar o evento "click" do botão Next do carousel, então pode usar o [`.trigger()`](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/) do jQuery.

Assim, seu código no segundo "if" da função starbar ficaria assim:

```
if ( vall >= maxx ){
    barr.value=0;
    $('.next').trigger('click');
    startbar();
}
```